# Pig Grouping Functions

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to get ,what item  was bought very recently by each person. Assume that a same person can buy many items.

below are the input details

```
kumar,2014-09-30,television
kumar,2014-07-27,smartphone
Andrew,2014-06-21,camera
Andrew,2014-05-20,car
```

I need the output as below

```
kumar,2014-09-30,television
Andrew,2014-06-21,camera
```

I wrote a Pig script upto this, but after that i dont know how to proceed,can somebody help me

```
A = LOAD 'records.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(name:chararray,date:chararray,item:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY name;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group,MAX(A.date);
```

But i need to get the item that was purchased recently by each person. How do i get that. If i apply GROUP then i am supposed to use only aggregate function in Pig.

How do i get the recepective item that was purchased?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bags and order by in a nested foreach, it will use only 1 MR job and is more in Apache Pig style.

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(name:chararray,date:chararray,item:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY name;
C = FOREACH B {
  ordered = ORDER A BY date DESC; -- this will cause secondary sort to optimise the execution
  latest = LIMIT ordered 1;
  GENERATE FLATTEN(latest); - advantage of PIG, that all columns are preserved and not dropped as on SQL group by 
};

DUMP C;
```

Also use of $0, $1 etc is convenient, but imagine you have a script with hundreds of lines and tens of group by and join operations that project using '$', it is nightmare to understand the flow of information/columns though such scripts. Time wasted in maintenance and making changes to such scripts is huge.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this works for you.

```
input.txt
kumar,2014-09-30,television
kumar,2014-07-27,smartphone
Andrew,2014-06-21,camera
Andrew,2014-05-20,car

PigScript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(name:chararray,date:chararray,item:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY name;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group,FLATTEN(MAX($1.date));
D = JOIN A BY date,C BY $1;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE $0,$1,$2;
DUMP E;

Output:
(Andrew,2014-06-21,camera)
(kumar,2014-09-30,television)
```

Comment: yes. Thanks for this ..looks good. i will try this. also can we use rank concept to achive the same logic

Comment: This solution is too much in the SQL style, Pig is not SQL it has bags. This solution will force 2 MR jobs instead of 1.